# How do I motion track a person and control an armature?

Tags: motion-capture

I am working on an animation series with fight scenes. Animating everything by hand takes a lot of time and doesn’t always look good. I was wondering if I could motion track a person with various markers and transfer the movement to a rigged character. Then movements would be smooth and realistic. Can I do this only using Blender or do I need special equipment and software? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `camera tracking` capability. The tutorials ([e.g. from Blender Guru](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-camera-tracking)) use it to track camera motion, but you could try and attach your rig to the tracked objects.

Haven't tried it myself.